# Can the duplication of type parameters be eliminated in this example?

Tags: c#, mvp, type-parameter

I have an implementation of MVP for a list of items from a domain model.

My question is generally how (or can I) get rid of the duplication of type parameters in the concrete View and Presenter?

I tend to think I've hit a limitation and have to either live with the duplication or redesign the classes. The other option is I'm missing something obvious.  Anyway, that's why I'm asking here.

Specifically, if you have:

```
interface IA<T2, T3> { }
class C<T1, T2, T3> where T1 : IA<T2, T3>
```

Can I get the compile to infer the type parameters T2 and T3, resulting in something like:

```
interface IB : IA<int, string>
class D : C<IB> { } // can't do this
```

This compiles.  The duplicate parameters are `Note, string` and `Attachment, string`.

```
// Abstract View
public interface IView<TItem, TKey>
{
   void Fill(TItem[] items);
   event SelectEvent<TKey> SelectionChanged;
   event MessageEvent Add;
}

// Event Delegates
public delegate void SelectEvent<TKey>(TKey selectedValue);
public delegate bool MessageEvent();

// Model Entities
public class Note { }
public class Attachment { }

// Abstract Presenter
public abstract class Presenter<TView, TItem, TKey> where TView : IView<TItem, TKey>
{
   protected TKey SelectedValue { get; private set; }
   protected TView View { get; set; }
   public Presenter(TView view)
   {
       View = (TView)view;
       View.SelectionChanged += OnSelectionChangedInternal;
       View.Add += OnAdd;
   }
   void OnSelectionChangedInternal(TKey selectedValue) {
       this.SelectedValue = selectedValue;
       OnSelectionChanged(selectedValue);
   }
   protected abstract void OnSelectionChanged(TKey selectedVaule);
   protected abstract bool OnAdd();
}

// Concrete Views
public interface INotes  : IView<Note, string> {  }
public interface IAttachments : IView<Attachment, string> { }

// Concrete Presenters
public class NotesPresenter : Presenter<INotes, Note, string> { 
   public NotesPresenter(INotes view)  : base(view) { }
   protected override void OnSelectionChanged(string publisherName) { }
   protected override bool OnAdd() { return false; }
}
public class AttachmentsPresenter : Presenter<IAttachments, Attachment, string> {
   public AttachmentsPresenter(IAttachments view) : base(view) { }
   protected override void OnSelectionChanged(string publisherName) { }
   protected override bool OnAdd() { return false; }
}
```

[image]

Comment: There are no "templates" in C#.

Comment: No, you cannot do this. The compiler cannot "infer" these types there because it is just a coincidence that in your situation they are the same. They don't have to be _always_.

Comment: doesn't `class Presenter<TView, TItem, TKey> where TView : IView<TItem, TKey>` constrain the second and third types of `Presenter` to the first and second types of `IView`?  If not then thank you for pointing out my misconception...

Answer (score 0):

Slight change to your presenter. Infer your view instead. Since your concrete views implement the right interface, it works. See code below.

```
// Abstract View
public interface IView<TItem, TKey>
{
    void Fill(TItem[] items);
    event SelectEvent<TKey> SelectionChanged;
    event MessageEvent Add;
}

// Event Delegates
public delegate void SelectEvent<TKey>(TKey selectedValue);
public delegate bool MessageEvent();

// Model Entities
public class Note { }
public class Attachment { }

// Abstract Presenter
public abstract class Presenter<TItem, TKey>
{
    protected TKey SelectedValue { get; private set; }
    protected IView<TItem, TKey> View { get; set; }
    public Presenter(IView<TItem, TKey> view)
    {
        View = view;
        View.SelectionChanged += OnSelectionChangedInternal;
        View.Add += OnAdd;
    }
    void OnSelectionChangedInternal(TKey selectedValue)
    {
        this.SelectedValue = selectedValue;
        OnSelectionChanged(selectedValue);
    }
    protected abstract void OnSelectionChanged(TKey selectedVaule);
    protected abstract bool OnAdd();
}

// Concrete Views
public interface INotes : IView<Note, string> { }
public interface IAttachments : IView<Attachment, string> { }

// Concrete Presenters
public class NotesPresenter : Presenter<Note, string>
{
    public NotesPresenter(INotes view) : base(view) { }
    protected override void OnSelectionChanged(string publisherName) { }
    protected override bool OnAdd() { return false; }
}

public class AttachmentsPresenter : Presenter<Attachment, string>
{
    public AttachmentsPresenter(IAttachments view) : base(view) { }
    protected override void OnSelectionChanged(string publisherName) { }
    protected override bool OnAdd() { return false; }
}
```